# Why does atmel use 39R pull-down resistor?

Tags: microcontroller, pulldown

I recently bought an SAM4S XPLAINED Board to get a bit experienced with ARM.
There is an external RAM on this board and there is a 39R pull-down resistor on PIN6 which is the /CS1 line of the RAM.

Complete schematic: [Schematic](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/sam4s16xplained/sam4s16xplained.boardScematics.section_ggo_tyg_xf.html)

[image]

**QUESTION**:
Why 39R is the resistance of that resistor? That is quite uncommon for me. I do not see any reason why should a strong pull-down be used here. I just want to understand the logic behind that.

Based on the schematic it's connected to PC14 of the controller, but it is not actually. (missing R208)

Comment: FYI, the "DNP" designation in the schematic means "Do Not Place". That is to say, R208 was left off deliberately.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that abbreviation. Still, I don't see that 39R  reasonable.

Comment: I don't have an answer for why 39 ohms, which is why I put that in a comment. As far as I can see, they should have used 0 ohms since R208 is DNP or 4.7K or 10K in case someone wants to connect R208.

Comment: Yes, 39 ohms is just as dangerous as a 0 ohm, as 39 ohms will draw in excess of 80 mA if a 3.3V signal is applied. That will certainly cause trouble. Maybe it is a way to protect from voltage transients on the ground plane??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a pull-down in the strictest sense that some other chip may be required to activate said line and fight against it. The chip in the OP's diagram is permanently chip-enabled as far as I can see and this is achieved by the 39 ohm resistor. If it were a zero ohm resistor would anybody quibble?

So why use a 39 ohm resistor instead of a zero ohm resistor - maybe there is another 39 R resistor used elsewhere on the board and they didn't want another line item in their Bill of Material: -

[image]

So it seems!

Comment: That would make sense if there were no 0R resistors already on the board. But there are.. (R199-R206)

Comment: Maybe the 0R resistors are a different footprint and won't fit in the position taken by the 39R - there can be several reasons including the idiosyncrasies of the designer.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The 39R takes less space than a 0R resistor used on the board.

Comment: +1 for the BoM thing. Will keep that in mind when reading schematics in future!

Answer (score 0):

A low ohm resistor here could be: a) a way to jump over some PCB traces {not likely}, or b) a way to present a logic zero normally, but allow a momentary
high to be applied (perhaps while testing the circuits).